# Can't Fetch All Rows

Tags: php, sql, oop, foreach

I want to get all room catagory's from the database! So that there are no doubles, as you can add multiple rooms with a specific catagory.

Here is my function:

```
public function loadRoomselect(){
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Catagory FROM room";
    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchObject();
    print_r($row); var_dump($row);
    echo("<label for='catagory'>Category:</label><select id='catagory' name='catagory'><select name='catagory' id='catagory'>");
    foreach($row as $catagory){
        var_dump($catagory);
        echo("<option name=" . $catagory . ">" . $catagory . "</option>");
    }
    echo("</select>");
}
```

For some reason it just gets the first catagory from the database! the Var_Dump gives:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["Catagory"]=> string(6) "Single"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
$rows=  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

instead of:

```
$row = $sth->fetchObject();
```

`fetchObject` only retrieves a single row

**Edit**

try this

```
foreach($rows as $category){
        var_dump($category);
        echo("<option name=\"{$category->Catagory}\">{$category->Catagory}</option>");
    }
```

Comment: Now it gets all of them in the Var_Dump, but now is none showed in the select menu! =$

Comment: Wow Thx so much!! =D Been stuck at this for a while! =$ Now it works! =D